# geom_contour error: "Not possible to generate contour data all z values are equal"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to draw a decision boundary from a training data set onto a testing data set with `geom_contour()` from ggplot. The decision boundary was from the training results of a support vector classifier. But it kept producing this error message:

> Not possible to generate contour data
>
> all z values are equal

Could someone help me with this? Below is my code.

```
#libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(kernlab)

set.seed(6758)
```

The data sets were set up so that they would have a non-linear but clear decision boundary.

```
#data sets
df_train <- tibble(X1 = runif(100, min = 0, max = 20),
                   X2 = runif(100, min = 0, max = 20),
                   Y = X1 * X2) %>% 
   mutate(result = ifelse(Y <= 90, "fail", "success"))

df_test <- tibble(X1 = runif(100, min = 0, max = 20),
                  X2 = runif(100, min = 0, max = 20),
                  Y = X1 * X2) %>% 
   mutate(result = ifelse(Y <= 90, "fail", "success"))

#for train()
X1_train <- df_train %>% dplyr::select(X1, X2)
Y1_train <- df_train$result
```

As I said, I was fitting an SVM, with `train` from `caret`

```
svm_radial <- train(
  x = X1_train,
  y = Y1_train,
  method = "svmRadial",
  trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
)

#training results
predr_train <- cbind(df_train, pred = predict(svm_radial, newdata = X1_train))

df_test %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = X1, y = X2, color = result)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_contour(data = predr_train,
               aes(z = as.numeric(pred)))
```

Comment: I don't have exact idea, why the error is thrown - yet, maybe tweaking the plot helps getting nearer to what you'd like to achieve: ```ggplot(predr_train, aes(x = X1, y = X2, color = result, z = pred, shape = pred)) + geom_point() + geom_density_2d()```

Comment: When I run your code I get multiple warnings including ```warning messages:
1: In grDevices::contourLines(x = sort(unique(data$x)), y = sort(unique(data$y)),  : all z values are equal``` You are inputting ```z = as.numeric(pred)``` which has only 1 and 2 values because pred is a factor. The ```contourLines``` documentation suggests z should instead be a "a matrix containing the values to be plotted". All told, my guess is you would need to calculate ```z```, and the numbers should fall within the range of your X1 and X2 data. I have no suggestion for how to calculate ```z```, however.

Comment: `ggplot(predr_train, aes(x = X1, y = X2, color = result, z = pred, shape = pred)) + geom_point() + geom_density_2d()` works, but the graph is not really what I was looking for. I was hoping to draw a decision boundary.

Comment: I don't quite understand why it says `all z values are equal` though. `z = as.numeric(pred)` has 2 possible values.